# How to move '__mocks__' folder in Jest to /test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have started using mocks in Jest for testing my NodeJS app and they're working nice, but it would make more sense to move `__mocks__` folder to `/test` folder so everything related to tests is there instead of mixing files in `/src`.

Is it possible in some way? I cannot find it anywhere in Jest docs.

Answer (score 15):

`jest.mock('../src/service', () => require('./__mocks__/request'));`

This has worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In my package.json i have some jest config

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.(ts|html)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/babel-runtime"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/setupJest.ts",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "mockData": "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/data",
      "mockService": "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/services"
    },
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/?(*.)(spec).ts?(x)"
    ]
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "output": "./reports/tests/TESTS-junit.xml",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  }
```

The "moduleNameMapper" part is what you need, I added these parts after my devDependencies. You can also create a config file elsewhere.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration

EDIT:

You have to modify these path :

```
"mockData": "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/data",
"mockService": "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/services"
```

So if you want Mock outside src folder you can replace my conf by :

```
"mockData": "<rootDir>/__tests__/data",
"mockService": "<rootDir>/__tests__/services"
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more how should it look like to make Jest look for iinto `/test/__mocks__` instead of the same folder as file?